# height issue AutoCompleteTextField CN1

Tags: codenameone

I have an issue with the `AutoCompleteTextField` component.

It is displayed on a form, which also contains a Picker (set with `Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME` type);

So before clicking on the picker all works well: the `AutoCompleteTextField` shows (after writing some characters) a list populated with `String` elements.

But after using the hour picker (that seems to display over the layer), the `AutoCompleteTextField` list already contains the `String` elements, but the height of this list is very short (`list.getHeight()` at only 9px, when it should be 105px).

Moreover, I noticed the same issue after using the `AutoCompleteTextField`  `setText()` method (even after performing a backspace operation).

For your information, I don’t use the `setCompletionRenderer()` method. I just use the constructor (`new AutoCompleteTextField` with `DefaultListModel<String>`) and the `setHint()` method.

Thanks for advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately the problem persists.
I try with this simple block of code:

Form form = new Form("test");

AutoCompleteTextField actf = new AutoCompleteTextField("Short", "Shock", "Sholder", "Shrek");

form.add(actf);

form.show();

actf.setText("Short");   //triggers the issue

form.revalidate();   //that does not solve the issue

form.getContentPane().animateLayout(0);   //neither

Answer (score 0):

After making a change that does or may trigger a change in the layout and requires a reflow of the UI you need to explicitly invoke `revalidate()` or `animateLayout()`.

See this discussion on [layout reflows](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/animations.html#layout-reflows).